# Identifying the application that invoked Location Service - Android location framework

Tags: android, geolocation, android-source, android-location

At some point in the android platform, I wish to identify the application that is requesting location updates although I realize that this violates the programming logic of the platform being 'context'-free.

I scourged through the android location framework and could not find a way to tag a LocationListener back to an application.

Is it possible to identify which class or package instantiated a particular object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Go to LocationMangerService.java in `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java`
2. Put in the appropriate places (for instance, into `requestLocationUpdates` method and also into other methods) a function `Binder.getCallingUid()`

So after that you'll know the uid of the calling application. I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the insight!I will try this out and let you know if it achieves the necessary results..
Sorry for this meaningless comment..will update it once I have some results!

Comment: This method works. I've tested it out and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I found a mediocre patchwork sort of answer to my question.
It so happens that the toString() method of LocationListener has an Override that returns the package name of the application that instantiated the LocationListener object. By using this, I'm currently distinguishing the applications.

However, I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution to the problem